# Start loading url in fragment from othere fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have two fragments in app. When user launch the app, in main layout fragment container shows first fragment, when user click on the button, second fragment replaces first fragment.

I want to do this: when app launch, in second fragment loading some text from the GET url request. And when user click on button to show seecond fragment, all text has already been loaded.

How can I do this ?

Maybe, make function "loadContent" in second fragment and when app launches call this function..

Is anybody have any ideas/info about this, please provide me^)

Comment: In your first fragment, make request and get the data from url. After that when you click the button, pass your data via bundle to your second fragment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the GET call in Activity's onCreate method. Define your own interface which has an abstract getter. Implement the interface on Activity, and override the getter to return GET response.

In fragment onAttach(Activity) initialize interface like :

```
 Interface callback = new Interface(activity);
```

now get the data, anywhere in fragment lifecycle after onAttach, from callback object like :

```
callback.getterFunction();
```